# Find duplicate values only if separate column id differs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
id   item
1    A
2    A
3    B
4    C
3    H
1    E
```

I'm looking to obtain duplicate values from the `id` column only when the `item` column differs in value. The end result should be:

```
1 A
1 E
3 B
3 H
```

I've attempted:

```
select id, items, count(*)
from table
group by id, items
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

But this is giving only duplicate values from the `id` column and not taking into account the `items` column.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does pandas have to do with this? Are you looking for Pandas answers or SQL answers?

Comment: Please don't tag spam. I've removed the conflicting RDBMS, and also [[tag:pandas]] (as it doesn't appear to be related). Just tag what technology you are using and is related to the question.

Comment: If you need a pandas solution: `df[df['id'].isin(df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['id']), 'id'])].sort_values('id')`

Comment: Apologies, I figured people that use pandas work closely with databases and SQL type queries.

Comment: That doesn't make the question about pandas though, @ApacheOne . Just tag what is relevant to the question, as tag spam means you are more likely to attract negative attention. For example, as this is about PostgreSQL I can't help you, as it was your incorrect tag [[tag:sql-server]] that drew the question to my attention; I don't know PostgreSQL. Some users might downvote you for such actions (especially if they had contributed to your question to find out it was invalidated by your mistagging).

Comment: Lesson learned. I didn't know of such rules but will be mindful moving forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function for this, this is generally *far* more efficient than using a self-join

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.items,
  t.count
from (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id) AS count
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.count > 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6ef0458025126ae50d8560f49d32e491)

Comment: Would you be able to write this for Postgres? it's telling count does not exist.

Comment: Updated for you

Comment: thank you, that was what I was looking for!